# How do I make compound columns with SQLAlchemy declarative?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I frequently make models with `Text` columns that hold Markdown formatted richtext. My models look like this:

```
class Document(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(250))
    description = Column(Text)
    description_html = Column(Text)
```

My edit forms (a) read from and write to `description` and then (b) write the Markdown formatted version to `description_html`. My (Jinja2) view templates (c) load the HTML version with `{{ doc.description_html|safe }}`.

I'd like to cut down these three recurring operations into one Column definition, like this:

```
class Document(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(250))
    description = Column(MarkdownText)
```

Where `MarkdownText` is a new column type that:

1. Makes two columns in the database table (description and description_html),
2. Upon writes to the column, also writes a Markdown formatted version to the html column, and
3. Provides a `__html__()` method that returns the contents of the html column. This will allow it to be used from a Jinja2 template as `{{ doc.description }}` without the `safe` filter.

Question: Is #1 possible? Can I define a column that makes two columns?

Comment: Do you really want to store both source and result html text in the database?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to cache it. Why waste CPU time regenerating it for every view or whenever the memcache expires, if it only needs to be generated once per edit? Disk is cheaper than CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go - now with composite columns:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import composite, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
Base = declarative_base()

class MarkdownText(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text
        self._html = "<html>%s</html>" % text

    @classmethod
    def _from_db(cls, text, html):
        mt = MarkdownText(text)
        mt._html = html
        return mt

    def __composite_values__(self):
        return (self._text, self._html)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._text

    @property
    def __html__(self):
        return self._html

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = composite(MarkdownText._from_db,
                     Column('_text', Text),
                     Column('_html', Text))

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = MarkdownText(a)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '(%s)' % (self.a)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add_all([Foo('test'), Foo('nips')])
session.commit()
x = session.query(Foo).all()
print x
print x[0].a.__html__
print x[0].a
```

And this gives us nicely:

```
[(test), (nips)]
<html>test</html>
test
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of answering to your bullet points, I better ask you this: "Do you really want to store both plain text and html text in database?". Here's how I would do it:

```
def text2html(text):
    # TODO: Implement me!
    pass

class Document(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(250))
    description = Column(Text)

    @property
    def description_html(self):
        return text2html(self.description)
```

And in view the html description can be accessed just as `document.description_html`...

Comment: To cache it. Regenerating HTML takes CPU time. If the typical document is rarely ever re-edited, why not just generate the HTML once and cache it forever?